# Download pdf from restful service with spring using iText

Tags: rest, spring-boot, itext

I have to downlaod a pdf file calling a rest api with spring. My code is the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "downloadPDF", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getPDF() throws IOException {

    ByteArrayInputStream bis = GeneratePdfReport.createReport();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=migration.pdf");


    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(headers)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
            .body(new InputStreamResource(bis));

}
```

and this is the createReport method that prints a simple table into the document

```
public static ByteArrayInputStream createReport() {


    Document document = new Document();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        table.setWidthPercentage(60);
        table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 3, 3});

        Font headFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD);

        PdfPCell hcell;
        hcell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Id", headFont));
        hcell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(hcell);

        hcell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name", headFont));
        hcell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(hcell);

        hcell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Population", headFont));
        hcell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        table.addCell(hcell);


        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
        document.open();
        document.add(table);

        document.close();

    } catch (DocumentException ex) {

        System.out.println("error");
    }

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
}
```

The problem occurs when I call the rest api and I get this error from the server

```
HTTP Status 406 – Not Acceptable

The target resource does not have a current representation that would be acceptable to the user agent, according to the proactive negotiation header fields received in the request, and the server is unwilling to supply a default representation
```

Comment: I solved with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159523/download-file-using-spring-restful-service

Answer (score 0):

The 406 response type from a service means that the response type service is returning is not provided in the Accept HTTP header in your Client request.

Since your service produces response type of MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE spring looks for a HttpMessageConverter. Spring tries to convert the error response to application/pdf but fails to find a suitable HttpMessageConverter which supports conversion to PDF.

So you need to add a MessageConvertor to the RestTemplate as in the following example:

```
ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter byteArrayHttpMessageConverter = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();

List<MediaType> supportedApplicationTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
MediaType pdfApplication = new MediaType("application","pdf");
supportedApplicationTypes.add(pdfApplication);

byteArrayHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(supportedApplicationTypes);
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
messageConverters.add(byteArrayHttpMessageConverter);
restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

Object result = getRestTemplate().getForObject(url, returnClass, parameters);
byte[] resultByteArr = (byte[])result;
```

Comment: I've tried to add `headers.add("Accept", "application/pdf");` but I have the same error.

Comment: if I remove `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response` I have an exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`